# Error while compiling C program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have written a basic program in C language in the editor of Visual Studio Code but I am getting the following error while trying to compile it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> ```
> [Running] cd "c:\Users\Chaitanya\Documents\initial\" && gcc pro1.c -o
> pro1 && "c:\Users\Chaitanya\Documents\initial\"pro1
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xb0):
> undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
> exit status
>      [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.198 seconds
> ```

Comment: Did you choose "console application" as the project type?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **console application** and **Win32 application**. You chose the latter but programmed the former.

A console application has a main function called `main`.

A Win32 application has a main function called `WinMain`; the linker misses it so it bails out.

Actually a Win32 application has a main function called `main`, too. But it is provided by the library it is linked with, and it calls `WinMain` after preparing some Win32 stuff.