# Error in compiling c program in gcc mingw running in visual studio code

Tags: c, mingw

My question has already been asked on your website and I have read its answers too but the answer give from your side does not give idea to to fix the error. when I compile my c program in visual studio code it is showing me an error as

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xb0):
undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
exit status
```

please please help me to solve this problem
here is the question i had seen 
[Error while compiling C program in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689617/error-while-compiling-c-program-in-visual-studio-code?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Link to the questions you are referring too and motivate why this is diffrent, otherwise there is a big risk of being flagged as a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show us any source code of your program and you didn't add any information about your project, I'm just guessing:

Most probably you have chosen a Windows executable as application type, but you try to compile and link a console application.

Windows applications have a GUI (graphical user interface) and therefore another contract for the main function. It is called `WinMain()` which is clearly stated as being missed in the error message.

For console applications on the other hand you have to implement the standard `main()` function.

Use the correct project type and it should work.